# Download data from ftp server not updated

Tags: vba, download, ftp

I am using the code below to download data from an FTP server, and it works fine, but data is not updated. So when I download file, if this file is updated on the server and I download it again, it will update the file but without new data (I saw that the date was updated but the new data is not present in the file when I compare it with the data on the same file on the server).
Furthermore, if I delete the file at the destination it will download it again but the same old one.

I think it downloads the file from the cache somewhere.

```
    Const MAX_PATH = 260


Private Type FILETIME
dwLowDateTime As Long
dwHighDateTime As Long
End Type


Private Type WIN32_FIND_DATA
dwFileAttributes As Long
ftCreationTime As FILETIME
ftLastAccessTime As FILETIME
ftLastWriteTime As FILETIME
nFileSizeHigh As Long
nFileSizeLow As Long
dwReserved0 As Long
dwReserved1 As Long
cFileName As String * MAX_PATH
cAlternate As String * 14
End Type


 Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetOpen _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "InternetOpenA" _
       (ByVal sAgent As String, _
        ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
        ByVal sProxyName As String, _
        ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
        ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long


 Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetConnect _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "InternetConnectA" _
       (ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
        ByVal sServerName As String, _
        ByVal nServerPort As Integer, _
        ByVal sUsername As String, _
        ByVal sPassword As String, _
        ByVal lService As Long, _
        ByVal lFlags As Long, _
        ByVal lContext As Long) As Long


 Private Declare PtrSafe Function FtpGetFile _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "FtpGetFileA" _
       (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, _
        ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
        ByVal lpszNewFile As String, _
        ByVal fFailIfExists As Boolean, _
        ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
        ByVal dwContext As Long) As Boolean


 Private Declare PtrSafe Function FtpPutFile _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "FtpPutFileA" _
       (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, _
        ByVal lpszLocalFile As String, _
        ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
        ByVal dwContext As Long) As Boolean

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FtpSetCurrentDirectory Lib "wininet.dll" Alias _
 "FtpSetCurrentDirectoryA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, ByVal lpszDirectory As String) _
 As Boolean

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FtpFindFirstFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpFindFirstFileA" _
    (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, ByVal lpszSearchFile As String, _
    lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal dwContent As Long) As Long




 Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetCloseHandle _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     (ByVal hInet As Long) As Integer



Sub Download_FTP()


Dim lngINetConn
Dim lngINet
Dim blnRC As Boolean
Dim username As String
Dim password As String
Dim serverName As String
Const ASCII_TRANSFER = 1
Const BINARY_TRANSFER = 2
Dim fData As WIN32_FIND_DATA
Dim Check1
Dim Check2


'****** Download 2G


    serverName = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(1, 6)
    username = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(3, 6)
    password = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(4, 6)
    localFile = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(5, 6)
    hostFile = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(2, 6)


blnRC = False


lngINet = InternetOpen("Microsoft Excel", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0) 'INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC)


If lngINet > 0 Then

    lngINetConn = InternetConnect(lngINet, serverName, 0, username, password, 1, 0, 0)
    If lngINetConn > 0 Then

        fData.cFileName = String(MAX_PATH, 0)

        blnRC = FtpGetFile(lngINetConn, hostFile, localFile, False, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0)


        InternetCloseHandle lngINetConn
    End If
    InternetCloseHandle lngINet
End If

End sub
```

Comment: If you manually go and download the file simply using ftp from command line do you get the results you want?  Make sure you are not getting stuck behind a caching proxy.

Comment: when i use command line i get updated files , but this code give me cached files (not updated one)

Answer (score 0):

add INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD as below

blnRC = FtpGetFile(lngINetConn, hostFile, localFile, False, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY + INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0)